Screen orientation issue - Ipad - React Native (Expo)
I am having an issue with React Native and Expo. Specifically, the screen rotation is not working correctly only on iPad devices. (iPhone, Android, and Android tablets work fine).
This is my code to detect the orientation, but using width and height from useWindowDimensions presents the same problem. The first render recognizes it correctly, but when rotating the screen, it does not update, and in subsequent rotations, the orientations are inverted.
const useOrientation = () => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState(Dimensions.get('window'));
  const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState(dimensions.width > dimensions.height ? 'LANDSCAPE' : 'PORTRAIT');

  useEffect(() => {
    const onChange = ({ window: { width, height } }) => {
      setDimensions({ width, height });
      setOrientation(width > height ? 'LANDSCAPE' : 'PORTRAIT');
    };

    const subscription = Dimensions.addEventListener('change', onChange);

    return () => {
      subscription?.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return { ...dimensions, orientation };
};

I tried updating the app.json with the correct orientation locks for iOS and Android, and also swapping the width and height when the height is greater than the width, but the problem persists!

Update:
it’s a bug in Expo only with iPad devices. I generated an app for the simulator, and it works correctly.

Any update for this one? How to fix it in iPad?

you don't need much state in your custom hook
also there is a react native hook that listens orientation change called useWindowDimensions
i would update that hook like

import { Platform, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

export const useOrientation = () => {
  const { height: windowHeight, width: windowWidth } = useWindowDimensions();

  const orientation = windowHeight > windowWidth ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';

  return {
    windowHeight,
    windowWidth,
    orientation,
  };
};


Hi! Thanks for the help, I have already tried with useDimensions. Anyway, I implemented your hook and when I rotate the iPad screen, the orientation inverts.
Example, first render:  (potrait)
{"orientation": "portrait", "windowHeight": 1180, "windowWidth": 820} - it's correct
Second render: (landscape)
not log
Thir render (portrait mode)
{"orientation": "landscape", "windowHeight": 820, "windowWidth": 1180}
